# How to Extract a Word and insert a string containing the word into an existing longtext field?

Tags: mysql

I'm nervously migrating and updating a MySQL database and for each record I need some help to achieve the following:

> 1. Extract the last word from the 'Name' column of a record
> 2. Encapsulate the extracted word in a string.
> 3. Replace the first character in the 'elements' column (longtext) with the new string.

**Example:**

The 'Name' column contains the following data:

```
Andrew Brewer
```

The extracted word should be encapsulated in a string to look this:

```
 {
    "0152cbf9-2bab-48dc-81e3-82d7b1b505ec":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": "Brewer"
        }
    },
```

The current 'elements' column begins with the following data:

```
 {
    "540aa2ad-9a8d-454d-b915-605b884e76d5":  {
        "file": "images\/profile-male\/ANDY_B_PROFILE.jpg",
        "title": "",
        "link": "",
        "target": "0",
        "rel": "",
        "lightbox_image": "images\/profile-male\/ANDY_B_PROFILE.jpg",
        "spotlight_effect": "",
        "caption": "",
        "width": 833,
        "height": 1163
    },
    etc...
```

We need the new 'elements' column to look like this (assuming that it's easier to replace the first character in a field than to insert it):

```
 {
    "0152cbf9-2bab-48dc-81e3-82d7b1b505ec":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": "Brewer"
        }
    },
    "540aa2ad-9a8d-454d-b915-605b884e76d5":  {
        "file": "images\/profile-male\/ANDY_B_PROFILE.jpg",
        "title": "",
        "link": "",
        "target": "0",
        "rel": "",
        "lightbox_image": "images\/profile-male\/ANDY_B_PROFILE.jpg",
        "spotlight_effect": "",
        "caption": "",
        "width": 833,
        "height": 1163
    },
    etc...
```

No special allowances for spaced surnames etc. is required
Any and all help gratefully received.

What would the query code be to achieve the above?

I'm a designer with HTML/CSS/jQuery skills but an absolute SQL novice and I haven't gotten very far today, despite spending 12 hours on this.

I've had intermittent results with obtaining the last name as some of the names have trailing spaces and are resisting the trim command.  Maybe they're not spaces but another type of whitespace?  In any case the idea was to reverse the string, find the first space, trim and reverse again, which is succeeding as far as it goes.

```
SELECT RTRIM(`name`),
  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(`name`), 1, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(`name`)) - 1)) AS LastName
FROM `artist`;
```

The next step would be to concatenate the string start+LastName+end then replace the first character of the 'elements' column but I have no idea how to do this.

If I'm in the wrong place to ask this type of question, please feel free to close this and I'll resort to editing the database manually.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project, do let us know if you have a question!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the autor forget to ask this question.

Comment: My apologies I forgot the question mark in the title. :o/
I have very limited SQL knowledge and I am unsure how to achieve the above with SQL queries. Thanks

Comment: You are simply asking us to make something, the point is to reach out when you get stuck. Show us what you have attempted and where you are struggling and we can help you on from there. Currently you are just asking us to make it for you, and you listed the requirements but not your progress or actual problem.